# Does javascript accessing an applet supports overloads?

Tags: java, javascript, applet

When I have javascript accessing an applet, can I have methods with overload in the applet?
Will javascript behave well with that?

Thanks

Comment: A demo for what exactly? It's a theoretical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically it should work.But there were some version of browser had some issues, that too in old version of Netscape Navigator.Also, if you use old versions of browsers it may not work.

http://www.en8848.com.cn/reilly%20books/books/web/jscript/appb_01.htm

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1311520

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Netscape is not really important anymore.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, yes, in all new versions of browser it should work after all it is a feature of java, not browser

Comment: It is quite comforting to know that it works. I am quite pleased with that scenario. I can set as prerequisites to use only newer browsers. Thanks a million

Comment: The only thing that makes me uneasy is the sentence "That problem has been resolved, however, and overloaded methods usually work now."... lol